# Django Admin FileFile not open from listview

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, filefield

in my model class i have an attribute like this one:

```
c_cv = models.FileField(upload_to='mysite/static/docs', max_length=254, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf']),validate_fsize], verbose_name="CV")
```

in my admin.py:

```
list_display = ('c_data', 'c_sur', 'c_name', 'c_dob', 'c_en', 'c_de', 'c_cv')
```

but when i open from admin my list page, if i click on my c_cv field in list i get an error because link does not start from 127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/static/docs/file.pdf but instead from 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/cv_list/...

How can i force in admin looking my c_cv field using root of domain instad actual path as prefix?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a URL for viewing media ? What have you set your MEDIA_URL , MEDIA_ROOT to in the settings.py ?

I have done something like this to access uploaded files:

1.In settings.py :

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

2.Defined a url which is used to serve uploaded media files :

In urls.py:

```
@login_required
def protected_serve(request, path, document_root=None, show_indexes=False):
    return serve(request, path, document_root, show_indexes)

re_path(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:], protected_serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

This way I can also stop directory indexing of the list of the files that are uploaded.You can try this